# Fetching thumbnails from PHAsset

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, phasset

I'm trying to fetch thumbnail as well as some other information from PHAsset.
Here is a simplified code snippet.

For all the images I retrieve from camera roll do:

```
static func fetchAsset(asset: PHAsset)
{
        if(asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaType.Image){
            let screenScale: CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
            let imageSize = CGSize(width: 100 * screenScale, height: 100 * screenScale)

            let options: PHImageRequestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
            options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.FastFormat
            options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeMode.Fast
            options.synchronous = false

            PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset,
                targetSize: imageSize,
                contentMode: PHImageContentMode.AspectFill,
                options: options,
                resultHandler: { (result, info) -> Void in
                    if (result != nil && result!.scale == screenScale) {

                        var newItemImage = MyImage(isLocal:true)
                        if let fname = asset.valueForKey("filename") as? String{
                            newItemImage.fileName = fname
                        }
                        newItemImage.thumbnail = result
                        asset.requestContentEditingInputWithOptions(PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()) { (contentEditingInput, info) -> Void in

                            //Get full image
                            let url = contentEditingInput!.fullSizeImageURL

                            newItemImage.url = url
                        }
                        //DO SOMWTHING WITH IMAGE
                    }else
                    {
                        //DO SOMWTHING ELSE
                    }
            })
        }
    }
```

I've got two problems at this stage:

1. The most important one but I guess it's consequent. It takes too
   much of processing power and reading from the disc. It works fine in
   emulator. But when I run it on test device (iPhone 5, 4S), which
   have 300-500 images, it freezes for a minute or two, while  getting
   all the images. I guess it reads through whole collection one by
   one, resizes it and fetches all this information. Is there are simpler way? Like it was possible with ALAsset, I could just get thumbnail directly and it was flying fast.
2. It does the job twice for some reason. First it gives me what I had asked for, small thumbnails ~ 60 * 40 or around that. Once it
   gave me that, after a couple of seconds it goes for another loop
   and starts to retrieve higher resolution images, like 960 * 640 or so, and that's where freezing is happening. I'm not sure why this is happening but it does.

Any input on these two problems will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It does the job twice for some reason

Because that's what it's supposed to do. Fetching images from the photo library takes time, as you've discovered. Therefore, the default behavior is we supply a low-resolution image as quickly as possible, just so you have something to display; we then call again, possibly several times, with better-quality versions of the image. Moreover, the fetch is being formed asynchronously. Thus, it is perfectly possible to end up with multiple fetch requests happening at once, which can cause your code to start stumbling over its own feet, as you've discovered.

If you don't like that, set the fetch options `synchronous` to `true` — but then you must make this whole call on a background queue! By doing this in a *serial* queue you can make sure that the calls are performed separately in turn, and each image will be delivered just once. Moreover, then (and only then) your `PHImageRequestOptions.DeliveryModeFastFormat` will be obeyed. Don't forget to step back out to the main thread before doing anything with the image you receive!

Comment: .Hi, thanks, but is there a way to retrieve the low resolution pics and say that's it? I can't find such option in documentation.

Comment: For one thing, ask for a smaller image size. You are multiplying your 100x100 by the screen resolution; don't do that. For another thing, you are supplying PHImageRequestOptions that are meaningless _unless_ your fetch options are `synchronous`! You are already asking for low-resolution results, but that's pointless until you do what I said. So please just _try_ doing what I said, okay?

Comment: I don't multiply if by screen resolution, I multiply it by screen scale, which is if I print out gives 1.0 or 2.0 so I assume it's the way to make images suitable for different screens.

Comment: I tried your way, doesn't do much for the resources improvement.

Comment: My question in general was, is there a way to fetch a thumbnail from the image, fast and easy, without reading through whole image collection and reading several GB of data, like it was possible with ALAsset.

Comment: "so I assume it's the way to make images suitable for different screens" Instead of assuming, look to see whether it's true. Maybe you are given an image that is _already_ correctly scaled.

Comment: "without reading through whole image collection and reading several GB of data" PHImageManager _is_ how you get the thumbnails. You are not reading several GB of data. You are only reading the data of the thumbnail size you ask for, just as with ALAsset. The only difference is that you have to talk differently. And this makes sense because of the way photo library images are now stored (they might be in the cloud, for example).

Comment: You can perhaps warm things up a bit and increase speed by using PHCachingImageManager. But it's ultimately all the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use this extension that I wrote:

```
import Photos

extension PHAsset {
    var thumbnailImage : UIImage {
        get {
            let manager = PHImageManager.default()
            let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
            var thumbnail = UIImage()
            option.isSynchronous = true
            manager.requestImage(for: self, targetSize: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
                thumbnail = result!
            })
            return thumbnail
        }
    }
}
```